# How to resolve this issue - "Can't resolve all parameters"?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I am trying to invoke sending a message using Ionic Native Plugin. I am able to install all of the components but whenever I follow the documentation. I have this error. Also, can you help me to directly send without opening the SMS Messenger App?

**home.page.ts**

[image]

[image]

**home.module.ts**

[image]

**IONIC Info**

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send SMS directly without opening SMS Messenger app via IONIC SMS plugin. you will have to trigger your SMS via your **backend/API** from third parties like **Twilio, AWS SNS** service etc.

Please check below link for send SMS via Twilio they have explained this on their website for almost all technologies. so I guess you don't need this IONIC SMS plugin anymore you can remove this and everything will work for you. If you still has an issue please let me know

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages